# What does "former" mean before a person's name in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

"He married the former Jane Smith and they had 3 children."

What does *former* mean in this sentence?

Comment: It simply means that the woman is no longer called Jane Smith.

Comment: "Former president" would be someone who once was president but is no more.  In the above, Jane Smith is now presumably named Jane SomeOtherName.

Comment: In some contexts you may see "Jane Othername (née Smith)" where née is the French for "born (with the name)"

Answer (score 2):

The lady's last name was Smith before the marriage. Now she probably goes by another name:

> Former: 2. Having been so in the past: a former ambassador; his former boss.

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/former)

Comment: Thank you all , the lady mentioned in the sentence was using her married name, but her husband mentioned her as the former Jane Smith my friend thinks they are probably divorced